# Delay after failing audit

Tags: support, review, review-audits

After failing a low-quality review audit in the First Posts, what is the delay between failing it and being able to review again?

Comment: There is no delay. You get your next audit when one is available. Though, I'm not sure what happens if you fail too many audits.

Comment: @Telthien He isn't asking the delay between audits. He said "between failing it and being able to review again?" And if you fail too many, you can't review for 2 days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's currently 10 seconds, which should be long enough for most folks to notice.